# Common prime of the finite number of order of imaginary quadratic field

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

This is from Silverman's 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves', exercise 5.5.

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field, and let $R_1...R_n$ be orders in $K$.
I would like to prove that there are more than 2 prime numbers $p$ such that $pR_i$ is a prime ideal of $pR_i$ for all $i$.

By using this, we can characterize supersingular elliptic curve as $End(E)$ is an order in a quaternion algebra.
Any reference is also appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $R$ is a (nonmaximal) order in $O_K$, then it has finite index in $O_K$. If $p$ is a prime not dividing this index indices, the obvious map $R\to O_K/pO_K$ is surjective and its kernel is $pR$, so $R/pR\cong O_K/pO_K$. Hence if $p$ stays inert in $O_K$, $pR$ will be prime in $R$.

Therefore, given a finite number of orders $R_i$, since infinitely many rational primes stay inert in $K$, we can pick more than two such primes larger than all the indices $[O_K:R_i]$ and they will satisfy the required conditions.

---

Proof that $R\to O_K/pO_K$ is surjective: let $[O_K:R]=n$ be coprime to $p$. Let $m$ be modular inverse of $n$ modulo $p$. For any $a\in O_K$ we have $na\in R$ and hence $mna\in R$ and $mna\equiv a\pmod{pO_K}$.

Proof that the kernel is $pR$: clearly $pR$ is contained in the kernel. Let $a\in R\cap pO_K$. Write $a=pb$ with $b\in O_K$. Since the group quotient $O_K/R$ has order $n$ coprime to $p$, it has no $p$-torsion, so $pb\in R$ implies $b\in R$, so $a=pb\in pR$.

Comment: $O_K$ means integer ring of $K$? 3rd line from the top, you mean $p$ stays inert in $K$?

Comment: Yes and yes. ${}$

Comment: Thank you. Where did you used the condition 「$p$ does not decide [$O_K$:$R_i]$ in the proof of $R/pR\cong O_K/pO_K$?

Comment: You need it to prove surjectivity of $R\to O_K/pO_K$ and to compute the kernel.

Comment: $xmodpR→xmodp O_K$ is surjective because the orders of $K$ are precisely the rings $Z＋fO$, and Ker $f$ is $｛x∈R｜x∈p O_K｝$＝$pR$.              Where did I used the condition                               「$p$ does not divide $[ O_K: R_i]$」？

Comment: I have no idea how your proof works. Consider the example $\mathbb Z[2i]\to\mathbb Z[i]/2$ ($\mathbb Z[2i]$ is an order in $K=\mathbb Q(i)$). Its image is $\{0,1\}$ so the map is not surjective, and $2i$ is in its kernel even though $2i\not\in 2\mathbb Z[2i]$.

Comment: Thank you. If you are ok, could you add the proof of 「$R→ O_K/p O_K$ is  surjective and Ker is $pR$」for me ?

Comment: @Nekojiru Done.

Comment: Why infinitely many prime number $p$ , satisfies $(p)$ is prime ideal in $O_K$?

Comment: This is a basic fact about quadratic extensions. It follows immediately from Chebotarev but you can get it quickly with quadratic reciprocity and Dirichlet's theorem on primes in APs.

Comment: Is 「prime $p$ inert in $Q(√m))$ if only if $(m/p)＝-1$」true? Then, how to use dirichlet's theorem on primes? If you are ok, I'm really appreciated if you could give this proof in the answer.

Comment: And are there any reference to the isomorphism $R/pR\cong O_K/pO_K$? Neukilhi's theorem 8.3's proof seems very closely to this isomorphism..(but different).

Comment: The equivalence is true for odd primes. To use Dirichlet you want to apply quadratic reciprocity to rewrite it as a statement about $p$ modulo $4m$. I don't know a reference for the last statement, it's really a result about quotients of abelian groups.

Comment: Sorry, about the isomorphism. The map $x→xmodpOk$ is  surjective because for arbitrary xmodpOk, x can be taken as original image? Why you take $mnx$ from domain? I think $x$ is enough.

Comment: If you pick $x\in O_K/pO_K$ and you lift it to an element $x\in O_K$, there is no reason to expect that $x\in R$.